# django shell showing wrong python version ? 2.7.6 instead of 2.7.10

Tags: python, django

When I enter django shell it shows:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
```

But in command line:

```
root@test:/home/django/django_project# python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.10
```

I am running it behind nginx/unicorn. Any other way to update it then using virtualenv ?

Comment: are you sure you are actually using the system python, and didn't download some application stack that has its own python built in?
in your django shell, enter:  import sys and print(sys.executable) and see if it matches your system python path.

Comment: go into django's shell (`manage.py shell`) and see the python's path using `import sys` and then `sys.path`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create a new virtual env. When you create a virtual environment, you can use the `-p` flag to specify which Python to use. Try

```
virtualenv -p /path/to/python2.7 myvirtualenv
```

where `path/to/python2.7` is the path to the version of Python you wish to use.